# Get missing values from database check

Tags: c#

As part of an application I have developed there are certain checks that are done to see if the necessary data is available in the database. This is done through the following functions:

```
    private void GetDataAndValidate(string connection, List<string> AdpTitles, List<string> OwnershipRoles)
    {
        var repo = new RecordRepository(connection);

        var adpTitlesInDb = repo.GetAdvancedProperties()
            .Where(i => i.Enabled)
            .Select(i => i.Title)
            .ToList();

        var roleTitlesInDb = repo.GetOwnershipRoles()
            .Select(i => i.Title)
            .ToList();

        var areADPsValid = ValidateTitles(adpTitlesInDb, AdpTitles);

        if (areADPsValid is not false)
            _log.Information("Properties found");
        else
            LogErrors("Warning", "Not all properties found in the database");


        var areRoleTitlesValid = ValidateTitles(roleTitlesInDb, OwnershipRoles);

        if (areRoleTitlesValid is not false)
            _log.Information("Roles found");
        else
            LogErrors("Warning", "Not all roles found in database");
    }
```

The ValidateTitles function is:

```
    private static bool ValidateTitles(List<string> TitlesInDb, List<string> TitlesToCheck)
    {
        foreach (var title in TitlesToCheck)
        {
            if (!TitlesInDb.Contains(title, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

This works fine however, I'm wanting to change it so the warning message is more meaningful than just something like:

LogErrors("Warning", "Not all properties found in the database");

I'm trying to get it changed so that the message will say exactly which property is missing, how can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```cs
private static bool ValidateTitles(List<string> TitlesInDb, List<string> TitlesToCheck, out string[] missingTitles)
{
    missingTitles = TitlesToCheck
            .Except(TitlesInDb, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            .ToArray();
  
    return missingTitles.Length == 0;
}
```

And then call it like:

```cs
var areADPsValid = ValidateTitles(adpTitlesInDb, AdpTitles, out var missingTitles);

if (areADPsValid)
    _log.Information("Properties found");
else
    LogErrors("Warning", "Not all properties found in the database, missing: " + string.Join(", ", missingTitles));
```

Comment: That's exactly the type of thing I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: @lross15 just for "correctness", I've made an edit as to how I'd make this method if I was to do it... the array return value doesn't really "show" what this method does and it'd need to be documented to actually know what the caller is to do with it (otherwise, I'd call the method `GetMissingTitles`, but not `ValidateTitles`). Having the missing titles as an `out` parameter and returning `bool` more clearly states the intention of a method with that name, IMO

Comment: that makes sense, thank you